# How to run Java Web Application from commandLine prompt or any where

Tags: web-services, tomcat, deployment, command-line, war

I have created two (java web applcaion ). one acts as a Server , I created ( web service) into. the second acts as client , I created ( Web service client) into .

I created them in netBeans, and they run .

but now I want to run them out net beans , how I can do this?

I want  any way to run out netBeans such as command prompt or an where.

if you have idia about running (.war) file , please tell me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What NetBeans did behind the scenes for you was to deploy your bundled and zipped source code into a servlet container (most likely [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)), which in turn takes care of everything between the webservice requests and your application.

1. Find out where your tomcat is located
2. Eventually stop tomcat manually via something like `TOMCAT_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh`
3. Copy your warfile into `TOMCAT_HOME/webapps`
4. Start tomcat (`TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh`)
5. Optionally observe the log (`TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out`) to find out about potential deployment problems

If everything went fine, you should be able to use your webservice with your client.